# Clarification on Firebase database

Tags: xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

I am relatively new to Firebase Database. I initially designed our Xamarin App using SQL as Server database. After analyzing cloud costing, i will have to move on Firebase.

App will have List view with Images, Map Coordinates and other details. Do firebase has any limitation on storing the data ? Whether images are stored in the firebase database? Whether there is a way to view the data in firebase database as similar to working on Management Studio?

Comment: Firebase Database is `NoSQL` and based on JSON data, while you *could* Base64/85 your images and store them as "text" within your Json streams, the recommended way is to store your mutlimedia files in Firebase Cloud Storage and store references to them within your Firebase Database.   The Firebase Console (https://console.firebase.google.com) is the management interface to your data and rules, remember this is a NoSQL/Json-based system, so you are not going to be working with the classic SQL table/row/column structure.

Comment: Given your requirements and how new you are to Firebase, I recommend you take one of the Firebase codelabs. They introduce you to the features you need. Search for "Codelabs" on this page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples/#codelabs

Comment: Thank you both. Very helpful on sharing the links.

Comment: if you decided to start with firebase, i suggest going step by step with this book. Helped me out.  https://www.amazon.com/Firebase-Essentials-Android-Neil-Smyth/dp/154666033X

Comment: @MohamadOl , Thank you, yes we are decided to go with Firebase